# Ranges V3 zip with auto and structured bindings

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, auto, structured-bindings

I would like to be able to use C++ ranges to help simplify code logic via zipping containers rather than explicitly indexing into them. I can get this to work with a verbose lambda argument, but I would rather try to make it simpler/generalizable with more `auto`.

```cpp
const int n = ...;
std::vector<float> a(n), b(n), c(n);

...initialize a and b...

// This works
ranges::for_each(
    ranges::views::zip(a, b, c),
    [](const std::tuple<float&, float&, float&>& v)
    {
        const auto& [a, b, c] = v;
        c = a + b; 
        std::cout << typeid(v).name(); // NSt3__15tupleIJRfS1_S1_EEE
    }
);

// This fails
ranges::for_each(
    ranges::views::zip(a, b, c),
    [](const auto& v)
    {
        const auto& [a, b, c] = v;
        // c = a + b; 
        std::cout << typeid(v).name(); // N6ranges12common_tupleIJRfS1_S1_EEE
    }
);
```

The [Ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) documentation says the following:

> `views::zip`
>
> Given *N* ranges, return a new range where *Mth* element is the result of calling `make_tuple` on the *Mth* elements of all *N* ranges.

This makes me think that I should be able to convert the `ranges::common_tuple` into a `std::tuple`, and I looked at the public members and found:

```cpp
std::tuple< Ts... > const & base() const noexcept
```

However this doesn't compile either:

```cpp
const auto& [a, b, c] = v.base();
// error: no member named 'base' in 'std::__1::tuple<float, float, float>'
```

But when I print of the `typeid(v)` it is not `std::tuple`; it is `ranges::common_tuple`. Is what I'm trying to do here with `auto` type deduction possible? (clang compiler if that matters)

Comment: In `[](const & v) { ... }` where is the type of `v`? Try adding `auto` as the type there.

Comment: Whoops, I had a typo. It should've been `[](const auto& v){ ... }` which results in the `ranges::common_tuple`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: don't use `const` if you don't actually need `const`. You want to modify something, so why `const`? This works fine:

```
ranges::for_each(
    ranges::views::zip(a, b, c),
    [](auto&& v)
    {
        auto&& [a, b, c] = v;
        c = a + b; 
    }
);
```

As does the shorter:

```
for (auto&& [a, b, c] : ranges::views::zip(a, b, c)) {
    c = a + b;
}
```

---

The reason what you have breaks is kind of subtle. Basically, `ranges::for_each` is constrained on [`indirectly_unary_invocable`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/2e0591c57fce2aca6073ad6e4fdc50d841827864/include/range/v3/iterator/concepts.hpp#L426-L434), which is requires all of:

```
        invocable<F &, iter_value_t<I> &> &&
        invocable<F &, iter_reference_t<I>> &&
        invocable<F &, iter_common_reference_t<I>> &&
```

So your lambda gets instantiated with all three of those types. One of those types (`iter_value_t<I>&`) is `tuple<float, float, float>&`. So when you do the structured binding with `const auto&`, the type of each of the bindings is `const float`. That's why it's not assignable - but that's only true for that specific instantiation (which isn't the one that gets invoked at runtime anyway).

Comment: Perfect! I had been using `const` since TBB had used it in an [analogous example](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/796816) and had run into issues trying `auto&`

Comment: suppose you wrap this in a function add(auto const& a, auto const& b, auto& c), then zip  + structured bindings won't work because of the mixed const/non-const. what do you propose then? drop the const on parameter a and b?

Comment: @TemplateRex Not sure I understand the qeustion. `auto& c` can deduce as const anyway?

Comment: I have a hard time reproducing my error in a small Godbolt example. Compiling on gcc with -Wconversion I get "choosing ‘ranges::common_pair<F, S>::operator std::pair<_U1, _U2>() const & over ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)". Turning the warning off compiles the code and everything works as it should. So the error is for "for conversion from ‘const ranges::common_pair<unsigned char&, const unsigned char&>’ to ‘const std::pair<unsigned char, unsigned char>’".

Comment: Here's my [Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/axErehshb) that doesn't trigger the warning. For now, `auto&&` seems to work when compiling with -Wno-conversion.

Comment: Never mind, I now realize I can simplify the range-for using `for (auto&& [lhs, rhs] : zip)` directly and then my conversion errors disappear.